# Undefined index: pImage lines 92,93,94

Tags: php

```
  $street_address = NULL;
  $price = NULL;
  $number_bedrooms = NULL;
  $number_baths = NULL;
  $sq_ft = NULL;
  $year_built = NULL;
  $featured = NULL; 
  $pImage = NULL; 
  //create storage for the checkbox values for featured house items. 
  $pool = 0;   
  $finished_basement =  0;
  $fenced_yard =  0;  

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {//checks to see if the user submit the form.
   // print_r ($_POST);  // This will show you what array information is being sent to post on the screen
   //print_r ($_FILES);  //can be used to view the contents of an array 

    // Gather the home listing data from the POST
  if(isset($_POST['pImage'])) {
$pImage = $_POST['pImage'];
  } 
   $street_address = $_POST['street_address'];
   $price = $_POST['price'];
   $number_bedrooms = $_POST['number_bedrooms'];
   $number_baths = $_POST['number_baths'];
   $sq_ft = $_POST['sq_ft'];
   $year_built = $_POST['year_built'];
   $pDesc = $_POST['pDesc'];

   if (isset($_POST['featured']) ) { //used to check whether the user selected if the home was selected as featured.  If they didn't the item is not passed to the POST.
      $featured = $_POST['featured'];
      } else {
      $featured = NULL; 
  }
    if (isset($_POST['pool']) ) {
      $pool = $_POST['pool'];
      } else {
      $pool = 0; 
  }  // this end bracket is "attached" to the process checking to see if the checkbox was 'ticked'. 
 //process checked finished basement box.
  if (isset($_POST['finished_basement']) ) {
      $finished_basement = $_POST['finished_basement'];
      } else {
      $finished_basement = 0; 
  } // end of finished_basement checkbox check 
   //process checked fenced yard box.


    if (isset($_POST['fenced_yard']) ) { // Fenced Yard Checkbox Process Check 
      $fenced_yard = $_POST['fenced_yard'];
      } else {
      $fenced_yard = 0; 

  } // end of finished_basement checkbox check 

  } // end of $_POST submission check (starts on line #40) 
  // Street Address Validation Check - See if address was entered into the form. 
    if (empty($street_address)) {
      echo "You didn't fill in a streetaddress. <br />";
      $output_form = true; // will print form.
  }  // end of street_address check 
     // Image , Price & Image validation check 

   // Price Validation Check - See if Price was entered into the form as a number.  
  if (!is_numeric($price)) { //is not a number function.
      echo "You didn't fill in price as a number.";
      $output_form = true; // will print form.
  } 

  // Used to store information for uploading images associative array. 
 $pImage = $_FILES['pImage']['name']; //array variable. Code pulled from 02fileglobaladd.txt document. $_FILES used to store file information from uploa
 $pImage_type = $_FILES['pImage']['type'];
 $pImage_size = $_FILES['pImage']['size']; 

// Image File Size Validation check -- checks to be sure that the uploaded image is no larger than 1 MB 
  if (!empty($pImage)) { // empty is for name of file. 
      if ((($pImage_type == 'image/gif') || ($pImage_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($pImage_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($pImage_type == 'image/png'))
        && ($pImage_size > 0) && ($pImage_size <= GW_MAXFILESIZE)) { // check to make sure that the file type is valid and that the file is larger than 0 but less than 1meg
        if ($_FILES['pImage']['error'] == 0) { // test to be sure file gets uploaded. 

          $target = GW_UPLOADPATH . $pImage; // try to move file to images folder // FILE UNIQUE time function added from book (page 252) that duplicates and chages file name if there
          // is more than one version 
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pImage']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 

           // Connect to the database
            $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
            // Write the data to the database
      $query = "INSERT INTO homes ( street_address, price, number_bedrooms, number_baths,  sq_ft, year_built, pool, finished_basement, fenced_yard, featured, pDesc, pImage ) " .
        "VALUES ('$street_address', '$price', '$number_bedrooms', '$number_baths',  '$sq_ft', '$year_built', '$pool', '$finished_basement', '$fenced_yard', '$featured', '$pDesc','$pImage')";

      $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error querying database.');
/*  Testing echos   
echo $query;
echo '<br />'
/**/

             // Confirmation for the user that will be displayed once the user clicks the submit button (As long as there are no errors with the PHP code)
            echo '<p>Thank you for Your Submission. The home has been added to the database.</p>';
      echo 'Street Address: ' . $street_address . '<br />';
      echo 'Price: ' . $price . '<br />';
      echo 'Number of Bedrooms: ' . $number_bedrooms . '<br />';
      echo 'Number of Baths: ' . $number_baths . '<br />';
      echo 'Square Feet: ' . $sq_ft . '<br />';
      echo 'Year Built: ' . $year_built . '<br />';  
      // featured if statement 
        echo 'Featured:' ;  
                   if  ($featured = 1)  {echo ' Yes <br />'; } else {echo ' No <br /> ';}
      //example of using ternary format of if/else -- additional items of home (pool, finished basement, fenced in yard ) checkboxes
      echo 'Pool: ' .  (($pool) ?  'YES'  :   'NO' ). '<br />' ;
      echo 'Finished Basement: ' .  (($finished_basement) ?  'YES'  :   'NO' ). '<br />' ;
      echo 'Fenced Yard: ' .  (($fenced_yard) ?  'YES'  :   'NO' ). '<br />' ;

               echo 'Desc:<span class="desc"> ' . ($pDesc). '</span><br />';
              echo 'Image File: ';
            echo '<img src= " ' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $pImage . ' " alt="Homes Image" /></p>';
            echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to Listings Page.</a></p>';

            // Clear the data in the form
            $street_address = "";
            $price = "";
            $number_bedrooms = "";
            $number_baths = "";
            $sq_ft = "";
            $year_built = "";
            $pool = "";
            $finished_basement = "";
            $featured = "";
            $pImage = "";
            $pDesc ="";

            mysqli_close($dbc);
          } //movefile worked....
          else { //movefile didn't work... error message is printed out 
            echo '<p class="error">Sorry, there was a problem loading your product image.</p>';
          }
        } 
      } //  no file type or size error / ENDING BRACKET 
      else { // there was a file type or size error / ENDING BRACKET 
        echo '<p class="error">The screen shot must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no greater than ' . (GW_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) . ' KB in size.</p>';
      }  // type size error message printed. / ENDING BRACKET


      @unlink($_FILES['pImage']['tmp_name']); // unlink is  php command to delete the file. Its getting rid of the temporary file. @ symbol ignores any error message. 
    } // data validated 
    else { // data didn't validate, show error message. 
      echo '<p class="error">Please enter all the required product information.</p>';
    }

?>
```

I added an if isset command to both the GET & POST statements, can someone help me. I know I have to fix up my code alot after fixing this issue. My professor mentioned about using the print-r statements...

Thank you for any help... I'm a newbie to PHP

Comment: Try to echo `$_POST['pImage']`: `echo $_POST['pImage'];`

Comment: where would I put that in the code?

Comment: You can put it before this `if(isset($_POST['pImage'])) { $pImage = $_POST['pImage'];   }`. This is to check if the value is set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['pImage'])) {
    $pImage = $_POST['pImage'];
}
```

As `$_POST['pImage']` is a image, you cannot use `$_POST`. To check is it's uploaded, simply use:

```
if($_FILES['pImage']['name') {
```

This will check for the name of the image, will return `true` when available.

---

This statement is wrong:

```
if  ($featured = 1)  {echo ' Yes <br />'; } else {echo ' No <br /> ';}
```

As you are comparing if `$featured` is equals to `1`, you'll need to use PHP's comparison operator `==`. `=` is used for assigning.

Thus, it should be:

```
if  ($featured == 1)  {echo ' Yes <br />'; } else {echo ' No <br /> ';}
```

More information on PHP Operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

---

Also, you shouldn't suppress error messages:

```
@unlink($_FILES['pImage']['tmp_name']);
```

Remove @ to enable error reporting. It's very useful in diagnosing syntax errors.

Comment: Should I take out $pImage = $_POST['pImage']; as well?

Comment: Changed it. After moving code around it worked. Thank you!